# Remove file sort to improve query mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, filesort

I have a problem in this particular query, i tried using index in receiving_table but its still using filesort, Mysql, database in general, is not my forte and im still learning the basics, i have 8000 records only and 7 seconds of query is slow, i attached my query and the database also, sorry english is not my forte also, thanks in advance

```html
1 PRIMARY re index PRIMARY,imei_index,imeibatchclientyear,batches batches 20  8326 Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY b ref PRIMARY,batch PRIMARY 26 tracking_system_1_schema.re.clientcode,tracking_system_1_schema.re.batchnum 1 Using where
1 PRIMARY hh eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 24 tracking_system_1_schema.re.imei 1 Using where; Using index
1 PRIMARY rm eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 24 tracking_system_1_schema.re.imei 1 Using where
1 PRIMARY si ref PRIMARY,imei,date date 22 func,tracking_system_1_schema.re.imei 1 Using where; Using index
1 PRIMARY h ref imei_index imei_index 30 tracking_system_1_schema.b.clientcode,tracking_system_1_schema.re.batchnum,tracking_system_1_schema.re.year 136 Using where
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY ssi ref PRIMARY,imei imei 17 tracking_system_1_schema.re.imei 2 Using index
```

```html
EXPLAIN
SELECT    
 b.clientcode  AS 'CUSTOMER', 
 b.batchnum  AS 'BATCH NUMBER',
 b.year,
 b.datereceived AS 'DATE RECEIVED',
 b.quantity AS 'BATCH QTY' , 
 COUNT(DISTINCT  re.imei ) + COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(h.imei, NULL) )  AS 'RECEIVE ITEMS',
 COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(h.imei , NULL)) AS 'SHIPPED ITEMS', 
 COUNT(DISTINCT  re.imei  ) - COUNT(DISTINCT IF(si.processcode = 51, si.imei  , NULL))   - COUNT(DISTINCT IF((hh.imei = si.imei OR rm.imei= si.imei) AND si.processcode != 51 , si.imei , NULL))  AS 'WIP',
 COUNT(DISTINCT IF(si.processcode = 51, si.imei   , NULL))  - COUNT(DISTINCT IF((hh.imei = si.imei OR rm.imei= si.imei) AND si.processcode = 51 , si.imei , NULL))   AS 'FGS',
 COUNT(DISTINCT hh.imei) + COUNT(DISTINCT  rm.imei) AS 'HOLD ITEMS'
FROM 
 tracking_system_1_schema.scanin_process_table si 
INNER JOIN
 tracking_system_1_schema.receiving_table re 
ON 
 re.imei = si.imei
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 tracking_system_1_schema.hold_table hh 
ON
 hh.imei = re.imei  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 tracking_system_1_schema.rma_status_Table rm
ON
 re.imei = rm.imei
AND
 rm.status = 2
INNER JOIN
 tracking_system_1_schema.batch_table b
ON
 b.batchnum = re.batchnum 
AND
 b.clientcode = re.clientcode
AND
 b.year = re.year
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 item_history_1_schema.item_history_table  h
ON
 b.batchnum = h.batchnum
AND
 b.clientcode = h.clientcode  
AND
 b.year = h.year
WHERE  
 si.dateandtime = 
 (
  SELECT 
   MAX(ssi.dateandtime)
  FROM
   tracking_system_1_schema.scanin_process_table ssi
  WHERE
   ssi.imei = re.imei
 )
AND
 (si.dateandtime <= NOW()
OR
 h.departuredate <= NOW()) 
GROUP BY
 re.clientcode,
 re.batchnum ,
 re.year
;
```

```html
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `receiving_table` (
  `imei` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `modelname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `batchnum` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `clientcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `dateandtime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `workerid` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `reusecount` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `gradebatch` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `serialnum` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `modifydate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `simcarrier` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ismanual` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `modelnumber` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fccid` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rmastatus` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `simtraystatus` varchar(15) DEFAULT 'null',
  `batchtype` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `withlcmmarking` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `year` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2015',
  PRIMARY KEY (`imei`),
  UNIQUE KEY `imei_index` (`imei`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `imeibatchclientyear` (`imei`,`clientcode`,`batchnum`,`year`),
  KEY `batches` (`batchnum`,`clientcode`,`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "filesort" is only one issue.  So I won't focus on it.  The filesort is essentially required by the GROUP BY.  And it does not necessarily mean that the disk it touched.

`AND  (si.dateandtime <= NOW() OR  h.departuredate <= NOW())`
Are there entries in the future?  If not, can't you get rid of this?

If you do need it, experiment with turning the statement into a UNION DISTINCT.  This would provide the opportunity for the optimizer to use an index including one of those columns.

The COUNT(DISTINCT)s would need to be outside the UNION.  That is, the UNION would need to be in a subquery.

This is a "correlated subquery":  `( SELECT MAX(...) ... )`  It has a covering index (good), but we don't know how often it is invoked -- possibly more than 8K times.  This *may* be most of your 7 seconds.  Try turning it into `JOIN ( SELECT imei, MAX(dateandtime) FROM scanin_process_table ) foo ON ...`, plus suitable baggage.

Note that making that JOIN will cause it to be the *first* table to be dealt with.  So, you would need `INDEX(imei, dateandtime)`.  (I am fuzzy on details here.)

A general problem with JOIN and GROUP BY is that the JOINs *expand* the number of "rows" under consideration; then the GROUP BY *contracts*.  Note that you had to do DISTINCT in the COUNTs to avoid the unnecessary duplicates.  To see how bad this is, do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( <your SELECT, but without the GROUP BY> ) x`;  I would guess it might be more than a million.  This, also, could be much of the cause of the 7 seconds.

So the general solution to that is to judiciously split the query into a query with a subquery.  Alas, I don't see an easy split.  Here is a partial solution:  Split `b` into an outer query.  Notice how the fields of `b` are not really used anywhere.  (`h` can be gotten to from `re` instead of through `b`.)  By pulling b.clientcode, etc out, the tmp table does not have to lug them around.  (Hence, the million-row tmp table will be smaller, hence faster.  But not a lot faster.)

You can experiment with splitting out b by simply removing all references to b.  Then see how fast it runs.  Then (if it is noticeably faster), use that thus:

```
SELECT b.clientcode ...
    FROM ( <all the rest> ) x
    JOIN tracking_system_1_schema.batch_table b ON b.year = x.year AND ...;
```

Make sure that b has `INDEX(batchnum, clientcode, year)` -- in any order.